# Run pkill without sudo permission

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, permissions

I want to run pkill like below.

```
sudo pkill -u 11002
```

I cannot give sudo password multiple times, so I want to run pkill without sudo user. For this i copied pkill to home as named bkill, and then i have run the following command.

```
sudo setcap "cap_kill+epi" /home/rajesh/bkill
```

This will give kill capabilities to this binary. But whenever i run i am getting following message.

```
 /home/rajesh/bkill  -u 11002
result: 31270
```

I check running processes of that user using below command.

ps -u 11002

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
340 pts/26   00:00:00 ncserver
```

This is showing process pid 340 is still running. I assumed cap_kill is not working.

So I tried a different approach.
I have given sudo access using below commands.

```
sudo chown root /home/rajesh/bkill
sudo chmod u+s /home/rajesh/bkill
```

Even this way also not working.

Can anybody help me to resolve this??

Comment: The process in question may be trapping SIGTERM. Try SIGKILL (`pkill -KILL` or `pkill -9`).

Comment: I tried those all signals. nothing is working.
Anyhow thanks for your reply.

Comment: It's possible that process is in [uninterruptible sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/a/223727/2072269), which is why signals aren't affecting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just give yourself permission to run pkill without a password:

```
sudo visudo
```

add

```
rajesh ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pkill
```

You'll still need to `sudo pkill`, but you won't have to type a password.