# kill process without inputting password

Tags: sudo, kill

**EDIT**
I ran the following:

```
$ echo $USER
goldy
$ hostname
goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th
```

`$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/kill` and added `goldy goldy-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/kill`

And tried rebooting. Still what I run `kill` I'm asked for a password.

Tho I notice this:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers | grep includedir 
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I didn't want to remove `#` without being sure I'm not screwing anything up :)

Is that the missing step?

Because It seems like that directory should be included by default:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/README
# As of Debian version 1.7.2p1-1, the default /etc/sudoers file created on
# installation of the package now includes the directive:
# 
#   #includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

**OP**
I have the following shell function to kill a port

```
function kill-port {
  PORT=$1
  sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:$PORT)
}
```

How can I run it w/o the need to input a password?

I've seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520072/run-pkill-without-sudo-permission) how to use `pkill` w/o password, how do I do the same for `kill`?

Comment: You can't kill a process that is not running under your user without `sudo`.  That's intentionally done that way, you need to use `sudo` to terminate the process if it's not owned by you.

Comment: I saw a way to add `pkill` to a user, so why not `kill`?

Comment: @AdamGoldman what way?

Comment: see here https://askubuntu.com/questions/520072/run-pkill-without-sudo-permission

Comment: That 'way' is to modify the sudoers to permit the user to execute pkill as sudo without needing a password.  It still requires *sudo* to work, it didn't actually 'grant' the ability to run `kill` as the user, they still need to call it with `sudo` to work.

Comment: that's actually what I want, updated the question to reflrect that

Comment: Updated the OP with the steps I did according to that link, it still asks for a password. Details in the **Edit** Section of the OP

Comment: You're running `sudo kill` and `sudo lsof`. Who's going to add the NOPASSWD rule for `lsof`?